# Passing text-box value from view to action method and return true false on given condition

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a text box and a button. If I put "adm" in the text box and click on the button, the value will get passed to the controller to an action method. There it will check whether the given value in the text box is "adm" or not. If its "adm" then it will show "true" in an alert box and if its not "adm" then it will return "false" in an alert box.
I am confused how to implement the whole thing. Please help.
I have been told to use jquery for that by my faculty.

This is my Controller.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
                public ActionResult Download(string name)
                {
                    return View();
                }
    }
```

This is my view.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#button1').click(function () {

        });
    });
</script>
<input type="text" id="text1" value="" />
<input type="button" id="button1" value="Button" />
```

Comment: An 'alert box' is client side (javascript) code. Why do you need to send the value to the server (as opposed to just checking it on the client)? If you do want to do this you need to handle the `.click()` event of the utton, make an ajax call to your controller which returns a json value (`true` or `false`, and then display the alert in the success callback.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, hello again sir. Its nice to get you back again. Can you please help me with the code sir?

Comment: You need to show your controller code and at least some attempt at your script - it would be something like `$(yourButton).click(function() { $.getJSON(url, { id: $(yourTextBox).val() }, function(response) { alert(response); }); });`

Comment: @StephenMuecke, please check sir.

Comment: What is the controller method you want to call - the one that accepts the value of the textbox and tests that it matches the text `"adm"`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, download

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79736/discussion-between-amit-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your controller method to

```
public ActionResult Download(string name)
{
  if (name == "adm)
  {
    return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
  else
  {
    return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
}
```

and then in the script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var url = '@Url.Action("Download")'; // add controller name is necessary
  $('#button1').click(function () {
    $.getJSON(url, { name: $('#text1').val() }, function(response) {
      alert(response);
    });
  });
});
```

although you could avoid the server call and just do the check on the client using

```
$('#button1').click(function () {
  alert($('#text1').val() == 'adm')
});
```